# need to replace a character "―" in a C# string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

i need to replace this "―" character in my c# string i used replace function in multiple ways it did't work. string and code example  is below:

```
string str="The Organisation of abc Cooperation ―OIC";
lbl.Text = str.Replace("—", "").Replace("&#8212", "");
```

Comment: `&#8212` is not a character escape sequence in C#. You need to use `\u` escapes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the case where copy-paste works - if you copy the character to string you are searching for it will work.

You also can use correct representation of Unicode charaters like:

```
   lbl.Text = str.Replace("\u2015", "");
```